# Installing fressh 18.04 Bionic Beaver unto new laptop and Nvidia-390 drivers cause DGM3 to hang on startup

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So as the title suggests, something is not playing well with the Nvidia drivers on 18.04. This was a fresh install on a completely new laptop. I have tried various things like nomodeset in grub, lightdm, etc..., but nothing seems to working. Does anyone have the solution or could help me better trouble shoot? I'm not a tech guru but I know my way around the command line. My system has integrated intel graphics as well as an Nvidia GeForce 940M card. Help please!

Comment: Searching AskUbuntu for questions [tagged 18.04 and nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/18.04+nvidia), I get 204 hits, quite a few of which have the same symptoms as you describe. Could you reference those with answers that you have already tried, and that did not work?

Comment: There is an open bug-report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053

Comment: Oh thanks guys. I'm new to this whole site and how things work. I'll subscribe to the one posted and make sure I post things that I have tried. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was never able to get 18.04 working, but a fresh install of 16.04 LTS with nvidia-384 drivers did the trick! I'll make sure to post this in launch pad as well.